# Material-UI Disabled attribute not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to disable the edit button once i click on complete but it is not working. I have passed in the state in disabled attribute but it seems not doing anything, don't know maybe because of setState's asynchronous nature. I passed callback while calling setState method and it seems logging data randomly, Can someone suggest what should be done ?

```
class App extends Component {
          state = {
             buttons: {
               id: "test"
             }
           };

          handleCheckBox = id => {
              let buttons = Object.assign({}, this.state.buttons);
              buttons.id = !this.state.buttons[id]
              this.setState({buttons}, ()=>console.log(this.state.buttons));
            }
          render() {
            return (
                <div>
                  {todos.map(todo => (
                  <List key={todo.id}>
                    <ListItem
                      role={undefined}
                      dense
                      button
                    >
                      <Checkbox
                        onClick={()=>this.handleCheckBox(todo.id)}
                        checked={todo.complete}
                        tabIndex={-1}
                        disableRipple
                      />
                      <ListItemText primary={todo.text} />
                      <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                        <Button mini color="secondary" variant="fab" disabled={this.state.buttons[todo.id]}>
                         <Icon>edit_icon</Icon>
                        </Button>
                        ListItemSecondaryAction>
                    </ListItem>
                   </List>
                  ))}
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `id` to change the state use `index` of Array to update the state

Create an array in Component `state` which tracks the `disabled` attribute of each buttons

```js
state = {
    buttons: Array(todos.length).fill(false),
      
  };
```

In `componentDidMount` initialise the array according to todos

```js
componentDidMount(){
    const buttons=this.state.buttons.slice();
    for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++)
        buttons[i]=todos[i].complete;
    this.setState({buttons:buttons})
  }
```

Now use the value in buttons state for disabled attribute of button based on the index of the component being rendered.

```js
<Button mini color="secondary" variant="fab" 
                  disabled={buttons[todos.indexOf(todo)]}>
```

Whenever `CheckBox` is clicked pass the index to the `handleChange` function and update the value corresponding to the index value

```js
<Checkbox 
    onClick={() =>this.handleCheckBox(todos.indexOf(todo))}
    checked={buttons[todos.indexOf(todo)]}{...other}
                />
```

```js
handleCheckBox = index => {
    const buttons=this.state.buttons.slice();
    buttons[index] = !buttons[index];
    this.setState({
      buttons:buttons
    })
  }
```

Comment: Hey thanks !!, Any clue how i can access props todos defined in render method in state and lifecycle method

Comment: By using `this.props.todos` instead of `todos`

Comment: Actually this props is coming from Graphql and i dont know if i m able to access props from render method why not from anywhere in the component.